# PHP signup form wont POST to MySQL Database

Tags: php, sql

Here is my HTML form:

```
  <form action="PHP/Signup.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="Firstname" required="true"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="MiddelName" placeholder="Middelname"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Lastname" required="true"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="true"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="true"><br><br>
    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email address" required="true"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone number"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="Class" placeholder="Enter your class code eks. 2MKA" required="true"><br><br>
    <button type="submit">SIGN UP</button>

  </form>
```

and here is my PHP code (PHP/Signup.php):

```
 <?php
session_start();
include 'PHP/ConfigMamp.php';

$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$MiddelName = $_POST['MiddelName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$Class = $_POST['Class'];

//Test to see if the form acctully gets posted
//echo $FirstName. "<br>";
//echo $MiddelName. "<br>";
//echo $LastName. "<br>";
//echo $Username. "<br>";
//echo $Password. "<br>";
//echo $Email. "<br>";
//echo $Phone. "<br>";
//echo $Class. "<br>";


$sql = "INSERT INTO Users
(FirstName, MiddelName, LastName, Username, Password, Email, Phone, Class) VALUES
('$FirstName', '$MiddelName', '$LastName', '$Username', '$Password', '$Email', '$Phone', '$Class')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: ../index.php");
 ?>
```

The lines i commented out was to test if the data was sent from one page to another, and i did receive the data but when i tried sending it to sql, it didn't reach or didn't get saved there. Can someone help me?

and here is the "PHP/ConfigMamp.php" file:

```
<?php
$Server = "localhost";
$Username = "root";
$Password = "root";
$Database = "BjerkeWeb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($Server, $Username, $Password, $Database);

// Check connection
// Remove mysqli_connect_error() after testing, leaves vulnerability to sql injection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "<a style='
color: green;
position: absolute;
bottom: 40px;
right: 40px;
'>Connected successfully to the database</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Does `mysqli_error($conn)` tell you anything?  How about your PHP logs?  You never check for errors, so it could be failing and you're just ignoring it.  (The fact that the code is wide open to SQL injection certainly isn't helping, since your SQL query could really be anything at this point.)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Try putting 
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1); 
then commenting out the last line header("Location: ../index.php"); and see what it spits out

Comment: your config and php file are both in same directory. use `include 'ConfigMamp.php';`

Comment: @RohanKhude I think you mean `include 'ConfigMamp.php';` but good catch

Comment: @Jake yes, i just to use `include('ConfigMamp.php')`

Comment: @RohanKhude Nice catch, write the same as answer and i will credit you, thank you all for the help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file you have included in your `Signup.php` is in same directory `PHP/`

this might work

`include ('ConfigMamp.php');`

**Note**: mysql is deprecated, you might get the sql injection. You must use `PDO` or `mysqli`